# ui:include внутри composite component

Tags: jsf, xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
     <composite:interface>
        .....
     </composite:interface>
     <composite:implementation>
          <ui:include src="/resources/test/includePages/testPage.xhtml"/>
     </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Тэг `<ui:include>` не работает в данном примере. Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Как именно не работает? В чём проявляется?

Comment: В браузере в html разметке остается строка  <ui:include src="/resources/test/includePages/testPage.xhtml"/>

Comment: может потому что `xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"` попробуйте как у других java.sun `xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Проклятый копипаст, я не заметил этот левый uri=(

Comment: На самом деле это новый url, который должен заменить url от sun. Что-то работает даже когда смешаны новые и старые, что-то не работает. В чём именно дело не знают наверное даже сами разработчики  реализаций JSF.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте faceltes таким образом:

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets
```